# In Judith 8:34 in Vulgate, it says: "Et revertentes abierunt.". What could it possibly mean?

Tags: latin-vulgate, judith

In Judith 8:34 in Vulgate, it says: "Et revertentes abierunt.". What could it possibly mean? "And they left while returning."? Is not that self-contradictory?

If possible, I would like you to point me to some translation of the Book of Judith into modern Croatian, as I cannot find one. None of the three Croatian Bible translations at bible.com include Book of Judith, for some reason.

Comment: Hi FlatAssembler, welcome to BH.SE - thanks for contributing! It's great to see more questions about books from the Orthodox/Catholic canons, as we don't often see these on the site. I suspect you're not finding this on bible.com as they aren't in the Jewish or "Protestant" canons. Hope you get some useful answers to this. Please do take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) when you get a chance, to learn more about the distinctives of the BH.SE community.

Comment: I don't know whether it will help, but the Greek LXX (Septuagint) which predates the Vulgate does include Judith, and a modern English translation of the LXX text is available [here](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets/edition/18-ioudith-nets.pdf)

Comment: It can mean either *turning around, they left*, or *returning, they left*. Both make logical sense. The Douay-Rheims chooses the former, while Wycliffe prefers the latter.

Comment: @Lucian What are "Douay-Rheims" and "Wycliffe"?

Comment: See [Douay-Rheims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douay-Rheims_Bible) and [John Wycliffe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wycliffe#The_English_Bible).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it meant they returned, and then left again, or WHILE returning to the place, they left another.

OR...does this help?
"Ali ne ispitujte o mojim djelima: jer neću vam to objaviti dok se ne dovrše stvari koje činim."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/51006)